# Persist IndexedDB in cordova app when app updates

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, indexeddb, indexeddbshim

I have an Android app built using Cordova. Version 1, which has been released for a while, stores some data using IndexedDB. I’m ready to release the next version but updating the app wipes all the data stored in IndexedDB.

What I noticed is that on Version 1, it uses cordova-android@^7.0.0 which uses **file://** as the security origin (I knew this from the debug tool). Then, on the next version, I upgrade the cordova to cordova-android@^9.0.0. Now, it is using **http://localhost** as the security origin.

[image: cordova-android@^7.0.0]
[image: cordova-android@^9.0.0]

is there a way to migrate all the existing data when the app upgraded?

Answer (score 1):

The only way would have been, in the previous version, to dump JSON data into a local file as a back up, then on the next upgrade, check if the local file is present and load/inject it back to IndexedDB. But it's probably too late now...
I don't see a solution as you are set up right now...

Comment: when upgrading the app, will it leave the file on the device?

Comment: it should yes...

Comment: You could also use https://github.com/globules-io/MongOGX

Comment: knowing that I still need to do something with the old version, I'll go with the 'JSON dump' solution for this upgrade. 
Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded from cordova-android@^8.1.0 to cordova-android@^11.0.0 and had the same issue you described.
I didn't find any solution or question besides this thread.
Just before giving up, I looked at cordova source and logic, and saw that there is a parameter called "AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled".
I set it to true on the config.xml  and it worked!
The app came back to use "file://" as the security origin, so after upgrade the app still logged in.

Later I searched about this param and found some docs about it so it's important to know the insecure impact of setting it to true. For now I don't have any choice but to use it. I hope that it doesn't affect or can break anything else...

Let me know if it helps.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/config_ref/

[image]

https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2021/07/20/cordova-android-10.0.0.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before but didn't work. AndroidInsecureFileModeEnabled only changes the https to http, not to file:///